# Capture and forward in nginx only headers which contains word "foo"

Tags: regex, nginx

I need to configure nginx for upstream and I need to capture only some headers which contains word "foo" and forward only these headers to upstream. Could you please tell how can I can capture and forward it?.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Could you provide a text sample?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have already found a solution. Unfortunately it cannot be done in vanilla nginx, but it can be done via the [nginx-lua](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/modules/lua/) module.

My code

```
header_filter_by_lua_block {
    local h = ngx.req.get_headers()
        for key,value in pairs(h) do
            if string.match(key, 'foo') then
                ngx.header[key] = value
            end
        end
}
```